# How to send custom data in Microsoft.Communication.RecordingFileStatusUpdated event of Event Grid

Tags: azure-communication-services

I am using `Azure communication service` APIs to start a Group video/audio call in my Angular / .Net Core application. I am also using the `Azure.Communication.CallingServer` to record the calls. I use the Azure Event Grid Webhook on the `Microsoft.Communication.RecordingFileStatusUpdated` event so Azure can notify my API when the Recording is available for download. All this works well and I'm able to download the recording stream.

The issue I'm having is trying to map the recording file to the meeting record in my application database. The event grid `Event Subscription` is created at design time in Azure and it cannot seem to pass any custom data. When the recording becomes available for download, can Event Grid send me custom data about the recording that I may have previously passed at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can persist the call ID and/or recording ID (a part of the `StartRecording` response) by the time you're starting the recording and then map the [RecordingFileStatusUpdated event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/communication-services-voice-video-events#microsoftcommunicationrecordingfilestatusupdated) to those IDs by utilizing the data in the `subject`.

Check out how [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-dotnet-quickstarts/blob/1f5473e8096b5eedbd679a48238e741c5473b11d/ServerRecording/Controller/CallRecordingController.cs#L118-L123) uses `recordingData` to persist the recording status.

Comment: Thanks.Is there plan to add a way to pass custom data when starting recording that the event grid can then send back? ours is a multi tenanted application and the Tenant/Database to connect to is unknown. Persisting the value in memory fails when scaled out and if the server is restarted and breaks the stateless nature of the APIs. We have had to create a new instance of the database that is not tenant specific just to do this. Though it solves the problem seems like a bad solution to a common problem. Would be great if we could pass data to the recording that can be sent back from Event Grid.

Comment: I'm not aware of such plan. Can you please repost what you've just described to https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/81ff6d2b-0c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858 ? It's an interesting scenario.

Comment: Hey, I noticed you were from the ACS SDK team. I had another SO question. It would be really great if I can get your advise on it. Link to Question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74037268/azure-communication-calling-devicemanager-getspeakers-doesnt-get-any-speakers