# azure-communication-calling deviceManager.getSpeakers() doesn't get any speakers on mobile devices

Tags: azure-communication-services

I am using `azure-communication-calling` library and [getSpeakers()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-communication-services/@azure/communication-calling/devicemanager?view=azure-communication-services-js#@azure-communication-calling-devicemanager-getspeakers) method on the `DeviceManager` interface does not return speakers list on Chrome on Android, iPhone, iPad and Macs. It does work in Chrome on Windows though. Does this API work on mobile devices?

Comment: you should be testing using Safari on iPhone, iPad and Mac as the JS SDK does not support Chrome browser on these devices as mentioned here [JavaScript Calling SDK support by OS and browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/calling-sdk-features#javascript-calling-sdk-support-by-os-and-browser).

Comment: Also, can you try calling `DeviceManager.askDevicePermission()` before calling `DeviceManager.getSpeakers()` as mentioned here [Enumerating devices on Safari](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/known-issues#enumerating-or-accessing-devices-for-safari-on-macos-and-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Speaker enumeration is not working on Safari yet, it's experimental tho and can be enabled from feature flags.

```
Before explaining how the Experimental Features of Safari work in iOS 16, we are going to list all the experimental features that Apple has incorporated into the advanced settings of Safari.

...

Also Chrome and other browsers on iOS are also basically Safari web views so it won't work there either.




Allow per media element speaker device selection
Allow speaker device selection

...
```